# Sorting an array of pairs using a given sort function

Tags: sorting

Let's say I have access to a stable sorting algorithm that can sort an array of integers `A`. So `sort(A)` would return the elements of `A` in ascending order.

I have an array of pairs of integers, that I would like to sort on the second element, where duplicates are possible. If duplicates exist in the second element, the array will preserve the ordering of the elements (it should be stable).

So if the `array` had entries :

```
(1,2),(1,1),(0,2),(3,2),(4,1)
```

Then the result would be :

```
(1,1),(4,1),(1,2),(0,2),(3,2)
```

Is this possible, using just the sorting function I am provided, or do I need to write my own sorting  function?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it for a while, I think this might work, but perhaps someone can double check that it makes sense:
I was thinking of creating a map such that if (x,y) and (z,y) are the only pairs in the array whose second component is y, then map(y) = [x,z]. In other words, given an integer x, this map finds the set of all integers y such that (y,x) is a pair in the array. I should be able to construct this map in linear time (in the size of the array of pairs) by looping through the array, and then after sorting on y, use the map to reconstruct the original array (again in linear time in the size of the array of pairs.).

Comment: Correct, so the total running time of the algorithm is n*log(n) (which is fine with me). I was wondering whether this would be possible to do without having to rewrite the sort function (which the above seems to accomplish). It does seem to have the disadvantage of requiring a lot of (linear) extra memory though.

Comment: I think the best way is `let array = [(1,2),(1,1),(0,2),(3,2),(4,1)].sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })`.

Answer (score 0):

array.sorted(by: { $0.1 < $1.1 })

Comment: What you have written does not make much sense to me. Where is my given sort function being used?

Comment: I think you need to rewrite the sorting function so it can compare the second item.

Comment: What if I removed the stability requirement for sorting the pairs?

Comment: but the sort function takes an [Int] as input, not [(Int, Int)], so I'm not sure how you would pass the array to the function at all.